# AS3 movieclip scrolling

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I ran into a problem which that I have a function "PlaceOneSpawn" which will spawn a MovieClip "A_Y" that will addChild into a movieclip Container.

Everything spawns and everything works, I spawn everything in the timeline Actions by calling the function.

I couldn't find a tutorial anywhere that shows a movieclip drag scroller (Like iOS scrolling) for vertical scrolling  with .y limiter using a class.

Most of the tutorials out there only use a direct timeline action coding, I want to try to stay clear of that type of coding if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial... tutorial... none needs tutorials for such easy task. All you have to do is to declare a `Point` in which you store the mouse position when the user clicks/touches and then calculate the offsets for the container when the user moves the mouse/swipes. For example, if the user clicks at (200,200), and swipes down 50px, then your container's y position should be `container.y-(200-50)`.
So as the user swipes down, the content goes up. And for a limit, just set a limit for the container's y position (must be negative).